# AssertionError (intersection of two line segments)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, geometry, shapely

I have an error when I want to find an intersection of two lines:

```
File "shapely/speedups/_speedups.pyx", line 87, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py

AssertionError
```

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
from shapely.geometry import LineString 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



d = {'x_data':[54.169958099157206,
 54.19352875826321,
 54.21789431944409,
 54.24006690055271,
 54.26417568849534,
 54.28785534158534,
 54.310803314281046],
     'y_data': [0.2869108125491426,
 0.2811692929873587,
 0.275376091452913,
 0.2695612150443841,
 0.2637546708603508,
 0.25798646599939185,
 0.25228660756008603]}

data = pd.DataFrame(d)


g = list(itertools.repeat(data.y_data.mean(), len(data)))
f = data.y_data

idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(f - g))).flatten() #points that intersect horizontal mean
print(len(idx))


x = data.x_data
#find intersection points
first_line = LineString(np.column_stack((x, f)))
second_line = LineString(np.column_stack((x, g)))
intersection = first_line.intersection(second_line)
x, y = LineString(intersection)


plt.plot(data.x_data, data.y_data, color='red')
plt.hlines(data.y_data.mean(), data.x_data.min(), data.x_data.max(), colors='k', linestyles='solid',)
plt.plot(*LineString(intersection).xy, 'o')
```

The error is in line:

```
x, y = LineString(intersection)
```

Error Traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "H:\script\intersect.py", line 48, in <module>
    x, y = LineString(intersection)

  File "C:\Users\ka\.conda\envs\work\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py", line 48, in __init__
    self._set_coords(coordinates)

  File "C:\Users\ka\.conda\envs\work\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py", line 97, in _set_coords
    ret = geos_linestring_from_py(coordinates)

  File "shapely/speedups/_speedups.pyx", line 87, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py

AssertionError
```

My intersection looks like:
[image]

My task is to find the point coordinates of interstation.
I am wondering why this error occurs, and how can I solve this problem. For some data it works but for some gives such error. I will appreciate any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is wrong with this shapely error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60825090/what-is-wrong-with-this-shapely-error-message)

Comment: I was also reading this but there is no clear solution how to deal with this

Comment: Please [edit] the question, and add an example set that works. Perhaps a comparison will lead to a resolution.

Comment: This question may have a better response on https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Make sure you're using the current version of the package https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/ and review [`.intersection`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.intersection)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I have version 1.6.4. I will update to the newest one